# How can I generate HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, html

Created a script that generates a table with 10 rows and 2 cols.

I can't make the cells generate **natural numbers nonzero, and divisible by 5** *distributed* as  the following table:
[image: table with ascending numbers]

This is my code:

```
    <?php 
$rows = 10;
$cols = 2;

echo "<table border='1'>"; 

for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){      
     echo "<tr>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
            //generated cols and rows, now the calculus
            if ($tr/5!=0) {
                echo "<td>".($tr*5)."</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td>".($tr*5)."</td>";
            }            
        } 
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Where did I go wrong, how can I make it go from row to row like the image ?

Comment: The two sides of your `if` are the same, and you're not taking `$td` into account. Remove the `if` statement, you don't need it - and then work out the mathematical statement you need to generate the number based on your two loop vars. If you are willing to do that, people will give you hints `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it more complicated than needed. Just add 5 to a counter each cell

Is this what you want?

```
$rows = 10;
$cols = 2;
echo "<table border='1'>"; 
$val=0;
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++){      
     echo "<tr>";
        for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++){
                 $val=$val+5;
                echo "<td>".$val."</td>";

        } 
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted!